# DataTables warning: table id=example - Invalid JSON response while pagination from server

Tags: ajax, datatables

this is my table

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width: 100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>latitude</th>
                    <th>longitude</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>latitude</th>
                    <th>longitude</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
```

this is my script

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#example').DataTable({
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "info": true,
                "stateSave": true,
                "lengthMenu": [[10, 20, 50, -1], [10, 20, 50, "All"]],
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "Default3.aspx/GetRouteName",
                    "type": "GET"
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "latitude" },
                   { "data": "longitude" }
                ],
                "order": [[0, "asc"]]
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

and at he end of the page i am loading the below script

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

this is my server

```
 [WebMethod]
public static string GetRouteName()
{
    List<location> b = new List<location>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        location l = new location();
        l.latitude = 1233;
        l.longitude = 123123;
        b.Add(l);
    }
    bise bb = new bise();
    bb.data = b;
    bb.draw = 3;
    bb.recordsFiltered = 1000;
    bb.recordsTotal = 1000;
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bb);
}
```

i keep getting `DataTables warning: table id=example - Invalid JSON response` i have tried so many turn arounds but same issue,all i need is to be able to paginate the datatable from the server because i have big data,but the ajax call is not even firing, reference this link [datatable from server](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/post.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetRouteName()
{
    List<location> b = new List<location>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        location l = new location();
        l.latitude = 1233;
        l.longitude = 123123;
        b.Add(l);
    }

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(b);
}
```

can you try this? is it working?

Comment: i think problem about a head. Getiing data and head not matching.Can you send ajax request data ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with .NET but I would suggest simply doing it this way to respect the desired format (this is server side pseudo code, feel free to translate it to any language you desire) :

```
function GetRouteName() // returns an object
{
    Array b = new Array();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        Array l = new Array();
        l.latitude = 1233;
        l.longitude = 123123;
        b["data"].Add(l); // Add the longitude/latitude array to a data field of the returned array
    }
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(b); // return the array b after converting it to json
}
```

Remember, your returned json needs to look like this :

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "longitude": "123",
      "latitude": "123123"
    },
    {
      "longitude": "123",
      "latitude": "123123"
    },
    {
      "longitude": "123",
      "latitude": "123123"
    }
  ]
}
```

It needs to be an object containing `data`, and inside that multiple objects having as key `longitude` and `latitude` with the proper parameters.